# how do I create a table in python? pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported an excel file into python and had to sort the data in a new table that I have to create.

the excel file looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpavO.png

the objective is to sort it in a 31 row x 24 column table. row being the different days of the month and column being the time interval (every 1hr). so 1st row of table will be patient arrivals on the 1st day of the October 2011 in different time periods (1hr interval for 24hrs).

as im new to programming, I'm stuck in a rut and I'm unsure of how to approach this task

```
arrivals_table = np.zeros((31, 24), dtype = int)
date = ['01/10/2011', '02/10/2011', '03/10/2011', '04/10/2011', '05/10/2011', '06/10/2011',
       '07/10/2011', '08/10/2011', '09/10/2011', '10/10/2011', '11/10/2011',
       '12/10/2011', '13/10/2011', '14/10/2011', '15/10/2011', '16/10/2011',
       '17/10/2011', '18/10/2011', '19/10/2011', '20/10/2011', '21/10/2011',
       '22/10/2011', '23/10/2011', '24/10/2011', '25/10/2011', '26/10/2011',
       '27/10/2011', '28/10/2011', '29/10/2011', '30/10/2011', '31/10/2011']

time = ['00:00:00', '01:00:00', '02:00:00', '03:00:00', '04:00:00', '05:00:00',
       '06:00:00', '07:00:00', '08:00:00', '09:00:00', '10:00:00', '11:00:00',
       '12:00:00', '13:00:00', '14:00:00', '15:00:00', '16:00:00', '17:00:00',
       '18:00:00', '19:00:00', '20:00:00', '21:00:00', '22:00:00', '23:00:00', '24:00:00']
```

Comment: The question is not that clear. Could you please create some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what is your input and what is the expected output.

Comment: I have added the code I have written so far. given the imported data from excel, I want to sort the data in a 31 row by 24 column table to summarise/tabulate the number of patients that visited the hospital each hour of a day (24hrs) over 31 days

Answer (score 0):

not sure on what values(columns) do you want to sort or if you have read the excel into a pandas data frame, but if you are using pandas you could take a look at this link:

http://cmdlinetips.com/2018/02/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-by-columns-and-row/

or refer to pandas sort_values

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

If you could paste the code you have written and how you want to sort, you will get a better answer.

Comment: I have added the codes I have written thus far in the question above